# Identify a TV show that involved dimensional travel?

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a show I saw when I was a child. I'm not sure what year it was made, but it could have been anything before 2000, really. I remember some overall plot features and details about a few episodes.

Overall Plot: The main character was a white male, probably in his early 20s. There was also an old man, a woman who was also probably early 20s, and some sort of small alien creature that I don't believe spoke english. Together these people travelled to different dimensions/through space (I think) on a ship.

They were being persued by a black male, probably about 30-40s who wore some kind of red armoured suit. Initially you believe him to be the bad guy, but I think there was a reveal where it turned out he was the good guy and the old man was the bad guy.

The following are some episodes, or parts of episodes, that I vaguely remember:

1) An episode that featured a character that was a human sized rag doll, possibly raggedy anne? I believe there were multiple 'toy' people.

2) An episode where the woman ate a piece of mushroom she found, which then turned out to be part of a 'mushroom person' and she fell ill

3) At some point the guy in a red armoured suit got trapped on a desert planet and couldn't get up. He tricked some wild old woman into helping him up and then he escaped?

---

**NOTE:** I am a big scifi fan. **I have seen all of the big tv shows like Dr Who, Sliders, Star Trek, Red Dwarf, etc. It is not one of them.** It is not going to be a big show, I wouldn't be surprised if it's one of those shows that had like 10 episodes and then got cancelled. I saw this in England in the early 2000s, probably on the SciFi channel, but I have a feeling it was either American or Canadian made.

I read a lot of science fiction as well, so I'm pretty sure it's not some sort of adaption of a popular scifi novel, so it's probably either an original piece or adapted from a relativley obscure source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Josh Kirby... Time Warrior!*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Kirby..._Time_Warrior!)

[image: DVDs of all six episodes]

> In the 25th century mankind has found a device capable of destroying the universe. Irwin 1138 separates the Nullifier into 6 pieces which he scatters throughout time. When the evil Dr. Zoetrope goes after the pieces, Irwin 1138 must try to stop him, with the help of a 20th century teenager, Josh Kirby, and a half-human warrior named Azabeth Siege. The race is on.

The living rag doll might have come from [the Toy World episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113486/).

[Chapter 5](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113488/) has mushroom people (video no longer available).

And yes,

> Irwin 1138 eventually turns out to be the bad guy all along.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. i've been looking for this for years... Looks like it aged alot better in my head than in reality though.

Comment: That often happens. :)